# Wireless network shows ghost copies of my network

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking

My router has a hidden broadcast. Let's say it's called Eagle. I've set my Vista Enterprise SP1 to detect it.

But after a while, something strange started to happen: on the list of available networks, I started seeing and Eagle, Eagle 1, Eagle 1 2, Eagle 1 2 3, ...

Today, I'm all the way up to 15.

And sometimes, there's an "unidentified network" on the list. If I choose to connect to that, enter the name "Eagle" and enter the correct passphrase, I have a succesfull connection.

Does anybody here have experience with that kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but it's worth mentioning that hiding the SSID of your wireless network [does nothing to increase the security of your wireless network](http://blogs.technet.com/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx). I'm assuming this is the reason you are hiding it, since I can't think of any other reason to do it.

Use WPA/WPA2 with a long key and forget the myth of hiding the SSID.

Comment: Well you learn something new everyday. The kids pressurised me to change my network from WPA2 to WEP so they could connect their Nintendo DS's. I don't think they've used the wireless since! I'll have to have words and change it back.